# Validate dropdownlist only if another textbox has a value - ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, textbox, requiredfieldvalidator

In my web application, i have a textbox and a dropdownlist.
My requirement is, i want to implement validation where it makes mandatory for the user to choose the dropdownlist if he fills the textbox, other wise the validation should not happen.

The code i have,

```
<tr>  
            <td>Returned On</td>  
            <td>  
                <asp:TextBox ID="Txtto" runat="server" AutoCompleteType="Disabled"></asp:TextBox></td>
            <td>
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlcond" runat="server" Height="26px" Width="156px" Visible="false">
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Working Condition" value="none"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Good-Usuable" Value="1"></asp:ListItem>
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Bad-Need Maintenance" Value="2"></asp:ListItem>
                </asp:DropDownList>
            </td>   
        </tr>  
<asp:Button ID="BtnUpdate" runat="server" Text="Update" Visible="false" OnClick="BtnUpdate_Click" Width="75px" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. On the btnUpdate_Click check to see if there is any text and route accordingly.

```
 if(Txtto.Text.Trim().Length > 0)
 {
     if(ddlcond.SelectedValue == "none")
      {
         //call alert (excuse the syntax I'm typing from memory)
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType, "err", "alert('Error You must select a drop down list value')", True);
      }
     else 
     {
         // your code to run here, page is valid
     }
```